# App Engine Deployment Failure - Max File Size?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-app-engine-deploy

400 Bad Request
Max file size is 32000000 bytes.  File "WEB-INF/lib/gwt-user.jar" is 32026261 bytes.

I've been deploying this app for years without issues and this file (gwt-user.jar) has been part of this deployment (it has not been updated for 2 years).  Anybody have any ideas as to what could have changed?

Comment: Maybe they fixed the max file size check bug causing files larger than the limit to be accepted? ;)

Comment: Could be, but seems unlikely they break deployment of GWT apps on AppEngine.

Comment: Well, the point of the check is to prevent deployment if limits are exceeded...

Comment: The question is, why are you deploying gwt-user.jar?

Comment: I am humbled...thank you.

Comment: @ElHoss is right, gwt-servlet.jar and the requestfactory server jar _may_ be necessary to deploy on your server, but gwt-user.jar never should be deployed or necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no recent changes related to  the file size in App Engine. According to the official documentation, the limit of each file to be uploaded is 32 megabytes.

[Deployments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments)

> An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each
>   file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. Additionally, if
>   the total size of all files for all versions exceeds the initial free
>   1 gigabyte, then there will be a $ 0.026 per GB per month charge.

I would suggest to :

1. Make sure WAR file contains only the essential libraries required for the application to start.
2. Use BlobStore for deployment of your App Engine app containing other dependencies (split up the necessary libraries) [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/blobstore/?csw=1).

Comment: If my answer was helpful , please mark it as accepted for better visibility for the community,